# Given a commutative ring R with a sub-semigroup H of elements with a desirable property, how do I extend H into a ring compatible with R?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

If I some ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ such that a certain desirable property is closed with respect to sums and negation but not necessarily products, then I can form the group $(S, +)$, where $S:=\{x\in R :\:x \mbox{ has the desirable property}\}$ and $+$ is induced from addition in $R$.

Can I glean anything interesting about the behaviour of the property under $(R,\cdot)$ from my group $(S, +)$?  $E.g.$, could I form a subring of $R$ with the set $S$ and some natural modified version of multiplication, thus allowing myself to apply both group and ring theory to analysis of the property?  In particular, could I determine certain conditions on elements for which the property is closed under addition?

I see an ultimately unsatisfactory analogue to what I want in exponential rings.  These give further structure to existing rings (with *both* operations), but there's no way that I know of to form an exponential ring from a group (with *one* operation).

I suspect the answer to be *no* without some further conditions, but what would those conditions be?

Comment: What if $0\in S$?

Comment: @Shaun Suppose that it isn't, or else switch $+$ and $\cdot$ in my description.

Comment: Your title and your question are *very* different! Your title suggests you have a group, and are trying to figure out a way to define a multiplication so as to make it a ring. But your description is that you actually have a multiplicative subsemigroup (or possibly subgroup of the unit group) of your ring, and you are trying to define a group structure on this that is compatible and will make it into a ring. Different things!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My abstract algebra is *very* rusty, and I grant that I'm not sure what I'd ultimately do with this structure.  What would be the answer to each question, so that I can mentally clarify and choose the appropriate one?

Comment: Or if you are trying to make your multiplicative object into the underlying group additive structure, then you need to be clearer. That is, if you want to try to find a ring $(T,\oplus,\odot)$, where $\oplus$ is the multiplication of your original ring, $T$ is the multiplicative group you’ve identified, and you are trying to define a multiplication $\odot$ on it?

Comment: Not every abelian group can be made into the additive group of a ring with unity. Of course, every *finite* abelian group can, since it can be written as a direct product of cyclic groups, so you can then use transport of structure with appropriate $\mathbb{Z}_k$; but that is unlikely to give you a particularly useful structure.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think your second proposal ("you have a multiplicative subsemigroup ...ring") is closest, and I'll adjust the title accordingly.  One point of clarification: subsemigroup simply means subset with a semigroup structure (*i.e.*, the intuitive meaning), yes?

Comment: “Subsemigroup” means subset that is a semigroup with the induced operation. The multiplicative structure of a ring is a semigroup (if your rings are required to have a $1$, it is a monoid); subsets of $R$ that are closed under multiplication are subsemigroups of that semigroup. If they include the unity of $R$, they are submonoids.

Comment: Also, you should say your ring is commutative *somewhere*. Otherwise you have no hope of using the multiplication as the underlying “addition” of whatever structure you create.